# Expectation propagation: $g_i(\theta)\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\Sigma_i)$ but $\Sigma_i^{-1}$ is non-invertible

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference

I paste here the section on Expectation Propagation from Gelman et al.'s *Bayesian Data Analysis* (pg 340). I have two questions:

1. In Step 5 (with the red box), where we infer the hyperparameters of the multivariate $g_i(\theta)$ from the moments of the univariate $g_i(\eta)$, how are these transformations motivated?
2. Also in Step 5, doesn't $\text{det}(\Sigma_i^{-1})=0$ as it is a scalar multiple of the outer product of $X_i$? If so, how are we meant to model $g_i(\theta)$ as $\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}_i, \Sigma_i)$ (see the preamble) when $\Sigma_i^{-1}$ is non-invertible?

---

[image: EP-Page1]
[image: EP-Page2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Regarding motivation, recall that for a model $y_i$ with prior distribution $\theta\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_\theta,\Sigma_\theta)$, the components required for getting the posterior parameters are the scaled mean $\Sigma^{-1}_\theta\mu_\theta$  and precision $\Sigma^{-1}_\theta$. These two are the sufficient statistics for the approximating distribution $g(\theta)$ (see Gelman p. 338). The exact formulae in step 5 use $\frac{M_i}{V_i}$ and $\frac{1}{V_i}$, which are the scalar equivalents of these statistics.
2. As in some other Bayesian methods (such as EM), the rigorous theory requires matrices to be PD but in practice you can settle for PSD. As I understand it, this is why you can "live" with $\det\left(\Sigma^{-1}_i\right)=0$.